# System Tray (Menu Extras) icon in Mac Os using Java

Tags: java, macos, desktop-application, system-tray

I'm developing a desktop application using Java. I want to put an icon (with a contextual menu) on the system tray (called Menu Extras in Mac Os). Java 6 comes with support for doing this in Windows and Linux, but it doesn't work in Mac Os.

I have seen some applications doing what I want in all three operating systems (e.g. DropBox), but I don't know if they are made with Java.

How can I achieve this?

If it's not possible in Java, is there any other cross-platform language able to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I have seen this work with Java on OS X 10.5 within the last year.  Show your failing code please.

Comment: Sadly, I have no access to my code now, but I can't paste it later if it's necessary. Is very similar (or equal) to this example: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/   The question is SystemTray.isSupported() returns true, no exception is thrown, but there is no icon :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### AWT / Swing

**According to [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/Java/JavaLeopardUpdate1RN/ResolvedIssues/ResolvedIssues.html), OSX 10.5 update 1 and newer support [`TrayIcon`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html)s**

> TrayIcons are represented on Mac OS X
>   using NSStatusMenus that are presented
>   to the left of the standard system
>   menu extras. The java.awt.Image
>   artwork for a TrayIcon is presented in
>   grayscale as per the Mac OS X standard
>   for menu extras.
>
> TrayIcon.displayMessage() presents a
>   small non-modal dialog positioned
>   under the TrayIcon. The ActionListener
>   for the TrayIcon is only fired if the
>   "OK" button on the non-modal dialog is
>   pressed, and not if the window is
>   closed using the window close button.
>
> Multiple calls to
>   TrayIcon.displayMessage() will dismiss
>   prior messages and leave only the last
>   message. If the application is not in
>   the foreground when
>   TrayIcon.displayMessage() is called,
>   the application bounces its icon in
>   the Dock. Message windows are badged
>   with the application's icon to
>   identify the which application
>   triggered the notification.

[noah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12034/noah) provided this sample:

```
java.awt.SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(new java.awt.TrayIcon(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("foo.png")));
```

Note that you'll probably want to attach a menu to that icon before adding it to the tray, though.

### [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)

**According to [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/R3_3/new_and_noteworthy.html), SWT 3.3 and newer supports [TrayItem](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TrayItem.html) icons on OSX.**

> Icons placed on the system tray will now appear when running on OS X in the status bar. 
>   [image: SWT TrayItem]

[This snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet143.java) shows how to create a menu and icon and put them in the Tray.

Comment: This works for me on Snow Leopard: 

    java.awt.SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(new java.awt.TrayIcon(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("foo.png")));

Comment: @noah: Whoops, yeah, I should have put in an example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it lter at home. I can't see any big difference with my code, maybe it's only a silly thing. I can't use SWT, but I'll try it likewise. Thanks.

Comment: The snippet is now located in [Eclipse's git repository](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet143.java).

Answer (score 1):

I ported a Windows application to my Mac with little difficulty.  One thing I noticed is that the icons are in full, living color (not following the Mac convention).  I'll need to add a little OS-specific code to convert myself.  But this is a big step up from the DLL dependent Desktop integration version from earlier iterations of Java.